# Converting plots to tikz code

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to convert the following plot to a tikz code[image]

I have seen from some previous QA that first png to svg conversion and after that svg to tikz convertion is possible. I tried to convert this png file to svg using online converter. After that I tried to use the `svg2tikz` python package to convert it. Unfortunately I found the website extremely unfriendly and only for professionals. Not a single example has been done there. I have understood nothing. I need help.

Note: I know to write a code for this image using `tikz-Feynman`, but want to know about these automatic converters, so that I can use for more complex images.

Comment: From the command line, you can use svg2tikz like this: `svg2tikz filename.svg`. If you have inkscape installed, you can also install it as an addon there to directly convert from within inkscape.

Comment: getting an svg (or any vector format) from a bitmap image will only work in very restricted cases and only if you are very lucky, you are constructing an egg from an omelette